# Code from Mathematica and Condensed Matter does not work

Tags: physics, input-alias

I found some interesting code from http://msstp.org/?q=node/252 , ( in Jason Harris material (save into the same folder).zip, jharrisPorto2010/Porto 2010.nb) the last two pages (39 and 40) contain some code in quantum mechanics.

I tried to copy the code and run in my notebook, but the code can not be copied properly. When I was running the code, there were a lot of warnings.

[image: The original code]
[image: Copied to other notebook]

Should I run anything before that?

```
    <<Notation`
    Notation[|a__\[RightAngleBracket] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] Ket[a__]]
    Notation[\[LeftAngleBracket]a__| \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] Bra[a__]]
    Notation[\[LeftAngleBracket]\[Psi]f__\[VerticalSeparator]\[Psi]i__\[RightAngleBracket] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] BraKet[{\[Psi]f__},{\[Psi]i__}]]
    Notation[\[ScriptCapitalH]_\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]Operator[\[ScriptCapitalH]_]]
    AddInputAlias[|\[SelectionPlaceholder]\[RightAngleBracket],"ket"]
    AddInputAlias[\[LeftAngleBracket]\[SelectionPlaceholder]|,"bra"]
    AddInputAlias[\[SelectionPlaceholder],"operator"]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no clear statement of your problem in your post. " there were a lot of warnings" is not an adequate problem description.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for the Notation package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) contains several sections.  In the last section, titled "Entering Notations", it says we must use the Notations Palette.  We cannot copy / paste the Notation commands into a notebook.

Here is how to get started with the Notation Palette:

1. Start with a fresh kernel
2. Evaluate ``` Needs["Notation``"] ```.  (There should be only one back tick after "Notation".)  Two palette windows should appear.  We want to use the "Notation Palette", not the FullNotationPalette.
3. Click the first menu item in the Notation Palette. That will insert the Notation command into the notebook.  The cursor will be in the first yellow section.  Do not click anything.
4. Type in the five characters "|a__>", without the quotes.  Press the tab key.  Type in "Ket[a__]", without the quotes.
5. Now evaluate the expression.  There should be no error message, no warning, nothing.
6. Test it by evaluating `Ket[ψ]` in an empty cell.  Mathematica should return |ψ> .
7. That should work.  If it does work, save your notebook.  If it does not work, go all the way back to step 1.

To put the hat on top of ℋ_ you can type `OverHat[ℋ_]`.  It is important that the hat goes over both the ℋ and the underscore.  You can also enter the hat from the keyboard with the Ctrl-7 and the ^.

If you are careful, it is also possible to paste into the yellow boxes instead of typing as we did in step 4.